# How can I test my serial port in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, serial-port

I installed Windows 7 in my system. I want to test my external serial port. But I can't find Hyper Terminal to test the serial port myself. Is there any alternate method to test it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or [TeraTerm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en). They are both freeware and easy to use.